# inadvertantly deleted memory.dmp file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I inadvertantly deleted memory.dmp file in c:\windows. Was this a bad thing? Will it recreate itself?

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

memory.dmp is a dump log from a previous crash. It can be safely deleted unless it needs to be debugged.
Should your machine crash again it will recreate it!

Answer (score 2):

It is bad only if you want debug or analyze your memory dump file.  [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139) you can read about memory.dmp file.